# Using useState hook in event handler results in "invalid hook call"

Tags: react-hooks

I am creating a web application that uses the Reddit API and I want to use the a dropdown menu to help filter which posts to display. But when I use hooks as part of the event handler function I get the error message `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`. Here is my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import validate from '../../app/login';
import './Header.css';

export default function Header() {
    const [view, setView] = useState('popular');
    const navigate = useNavigate;

    useEffect(() => {
        navigate(`/${view}`);
    }, [view]);

    function handleChange(e) {
        setView(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div className='Header' role='Header'>
            <span className='header-left'>
                <h1>RedditLite</h1>
                <label htmlFor='mode-select'>View Mode: </label>
                <select name='mode-select' id='mode-select' onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
                    <option value='popular' selected>Most Popular</option>
                    <option value='communities'>By Community</option>
                    <option value='profile'>By Profile Category</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            <input
                type='text'
                id='searchbar'
                name='searchbar'
                placeholder='Search RedditLite'
            />
            <span className='header-right'>
                <h3 role='button' onClick={validate}>Login</h3>
            </span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So which rule of hooks is my implementation violating?

EDIT: Turns out I forgot to put brackets in front of `const navigate = useNavigate` and I was calling `useNavigate` incorrectly. Whoops

Comment: Call the `useNavigate` hook - `const navigate = useNavigate();`. Right now you just alias `useNavigate` as `navigate`, and you try to use the hook inside `useEffect`.

Comment: It works! Thanks for pointing that out. I can't believe I overlooked such an obvious typo.